# SQL to detect inconsistency between 1:M and M:M relations

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

I have four tables in a Django app that is backed by a PostgreSQL DB:

- Customer
- SalesOrder
- UserGroup
- CustomerToUserGroupMembership

There is a standard foreign key from SalesOrder to UserGroup and there is a M:M relation between Customer and UserGroup.  All tables have a `uuid` column that acts as the PK.

Ultimately I am trying to find orders with a fast SQL query that would be expressed in Python condition as `order.userGroup not in order.customer.userGroups.all()`.

I tried something like:

```
SELECT o.uuid 
FROM myapp_salesorder o JOIN myapp_customer c ON o.customer_id = c.uuid
WHERE o."userGroup_id" NOT IN (
    SELECT m."userGroup_id" FROM myapp_customertousergroupmembership m 
    WHERE m.customer_id = c.uuid
);
```

... but the sub-select really slows that down.

Is there a better way to craft this to make it faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different approaches to this.  For your case, I would use `not exists`:

```
SELECT o.uuid 
FROM myapp_salesorder o JOIN
     myapp_customer c
     ON o.customer_id = c.uuid
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM myapp_customertousergroupmembership m 
                  WHERE m.customer_id = c.uuid AND m.userGroup_id = o.userGroup_id
                 );
```

For optimal performance, create a compound index on `myapp_customertousergroupmembership(customer_id, userGroup_id)`.

EDIT:

The `join` version is easy enough:

```
SELECT o.uuid 
FROM myapp_salesorder o JOIN
     myapp_customer c
     ON o.customer_id = c.uuid LEFT JOIN
     myapp_customertousergroupmembership m
     ON m.customer_id = c.uuid AND m.userGroup_id = o.userGroup_id
WHERE m.customer_id IS NULL;
```

I don't know if the performance will be any better, though.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I tried running this version instead with postgres timing turned on and it came up slightly slower in a restricted subset of the database.  My version took 796ms and yours took 821ms.  Is there any way to do this with pure JOINs and no subselects?

Comment: Sorry: @Gordon Linoffs plan cannot be slower unless you cheat.

Comment: I discovered that the results from the query in my original question are actually wrong (it returns more results than it should, although I'm not sure why), so by that measure the speed difference is irrelevant and Gordon's answer was very helpful.